# Multithread ifstream/ofstream

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a single "Resource Module" class that manages all resources for my application, and it reads mainly from a single file "*RESOURCES.DAT*" where everything is.

All objects that request new data from the file go through the ResourceModule so I can manage memory and avoid duplicate resources.

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    Image* newImage = new Image();
    newImage->Load("imageName");
}

void Image::Load(string imageName)
{
    //Pointer to Image Data
    _myImage = ResourceModule::GetResource(imageName);
}
```

There's always only one ResourceModule.
I want to make it multithread safe, so when the *GetResource(string resourceName)* is called, it doesn't bug out.

If I do this:

```
Image* ResourceModule::GetResource(string imageName)
{
    ifstream fileReader;
    fileReader.open("RESOURCES.DAT", ios::binary);
    if(fileReader.is_open())
    {
        //Do the reading, return the pointer
    }
}
```

Is this multithread safe? Do multiple ifstreams/ofstreams conflict with each other when I declare them like this and read from the **same** file?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754303/is-stdifstream-thread-safe-lock-free

Comment: The reading of files is safe to do concurrently; if/when you decide you want to cache the read file data in memory (e.g. so that the second time a resource is requested, it doesn't have to be read in from disk again), you would need to serialize access to the data structure that holds the cached data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

**it will work as it is read only**,
every instance of ifstream will read. But that will not be a problem.
Every ifstream will have it's own position in the file, and progress in parallel.

You don't need to do anything